# window.close() not working in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

In Microsoft Edge, `window.close()` is not working in child windows after closing a print dialog.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a print dialog from a child window.
2. Close it.

After closing the print dialog, the close button of the child window is not closing it.

### Code for parent window:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function openChild(){ 
       window.open("childWindow.html", "", "width=600, height=400"); 
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Open Child Window" onclick="openChild()" />
    </body>
```

### Code for child window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeWindow(){
        window.close();
    }
    function printPage() {
        window.print();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printPage()" />
        <input type="button" value="Close Window" onclick="closeWindow()" style="float: right" />
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure if this is related, but I saw an article where window.close() will not work  in edge after a print dialog has been canceled. Maybe it is the same bug? [Microsoft support article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/edge-browser-windowclose-not-working-if-print-is/737abfbf-d9af-4469-8d67-6ec9288d420f)

Comment: Its the same bug even today version 40 of Edge